# How can I create an instance of this class?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using `PhoneGap` to develop an plug-in for a Heart Rate Monitor, it has the following header file in their SDK:

```
@class HRMonitor;

@interface HRMonitor : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate>{

}

-(id) init: (id) _delegate;
-(void)startup;
-(void)shutdown;
```

I just listed the Method that I'm having trouble with.

I also have a class `HRMPlugin.m`, but inside this class, whenever I want to create an instance:

```
HRMonitor *hrm = [[HRMonitor alloc] init:self]
```

It will report an error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/octref/Documents/HRM/HRMPlugin/iOS_APP_SDK_r5/libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/octref/Documents/HRM/HRMPlugin/iOS_APP_SDK_r5/libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HRMonitor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HRMPlugin-9E97FDE3BF57274E.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm new to `iOS` and don't know what to do. Is my way of creating a new instance correct?
How can I debug my code?

Comment: did you `#import "HRMonitor.h"` ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor There is only a mytrekSDK.h in the SDK, and yes I have `#import "mytrekSDK.h"`, I also have `#import "HRMPlugin.h"` which is the header of my "HRMPlugin.m"

Comment: is the build result the same when you target iOS Device to compile ?

Comment: It's not the same, this time it says:The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains , the original error is gone.. I guess that's not the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

The reason of your error is:

The library you use does not support iOS Simulator.

For the 2nd error, please make sure you have a valid Apple Developer Account with Developer Certificate and Provisioning Profile ( Team Provisioning Profile is also okay ).

Comment: I'll try it on a iOS device tomorrow, and after that I would mark your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: sure. let us know if you have further problem